# Flex Hero spark component - changing view from within custom itemrenderer

Tags: apache-flex, itemrenderer

I've made a custom list itemRenderer with 2 buttons and a label. One button deletes the list entry (and thats not the problem) the second button would change the actual view.
Does anyone knows how I can change actual view within the itemrenderer ?

Comment: When you say "changing the view" what exactly are you trying to do? Change the `ItemRenderer`'s state? Modify a `ViewStack`? Show/hide a component? Posting some of your code would probably help us help you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I think I understand, you want to change a viewstack or something.  What you want to do is bubble an event from the itemRenderer up to a point in the display list where someone will listen and trigger an event handler which then changes the view.

So, in your itemRenderer do

```
dispatchEvent(new Event('someEventName', true));
```

And up the display list you need to listen for that even

```
this.addEventListener('someEventName', someHandlerFunction);
```

And in that function just switch your view or whatever else you want.